# How to launch rxbag or rqt_bag with the --clock option

Tags: ros, rosbag, rxbag, clock, rqt-bag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am launching the playback of a bag file using rosbag play.

Because I want to emulate the clock at the time of recording I use the --clock option along with the use_sim_time=true parameter

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Clock

The problem is I want tot use rxbag or rqt_bag instead of rosbag play.

None of those accept a --clock option.

I should I do it? run a clock server independently? How can I do it?

Thanks

Miguel

Update: No one answered my question. If it does not make sense please let me know. Basically, I just want to know how I can emulate the use_sim_time --clock options with rxbag or rqt_Bag.
Thanks

Miguel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62729/how-to-launch-rxbag-or-rqt_bag-with-the---clock-option/) by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 254 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-05-21**:
I have a question : why would you want not to use rosbag play ? Is there any particular reason, advantages in rxbag or rqt_bag ? (except the graphical interface)

**Comment by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on 2013-05-23**:
Hi Stephane

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-05-23**:
hi ! You did not answer my question :-)

**Comment by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on 2013-05-23**:
Sorry. Had a problem with the browser. Yes there are many advantages. With rxbag or rqt_bag you can move forward or backward in time, jump to a specific time in the bag, change in real time the playback rate, etc. There are many advantages. Regards Miguel

**Comment by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) on 2013-07-15**:
Created a ticket: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/102

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-09-17**:
I was looking for that just now! Thanks for creating the ticket, I totally back this feature.

**Comment by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on 2015-08-10**:
I see now that the option is available from the help. But it does not work. If i run rqt_bag --clock mybag.bag and do rostopic echo /clock after pressing the play button nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So this doesn't show up as unanswered anymore:

As a result of the issue created this capability was added here:
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/204

---

Originally posted by [Aaron Blasdel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3372/aaron-blasdel/) with karma: 211 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3